# Problems with sorting comments in a SEF url system

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

I use [Commentics](http://www.commentics.org) for my website and having problem with my SEF urls. I couldn't find a solution in the related forum.

I have a rewrite rule like this :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /kurum.php?sef=$1
```

so my urls like http://fxrehber.com/kurum.php?sef=xtb

turns into this:

http://fxrehber.com/xtb

When I try to sort comments, that does not work

My url look like this :

http://fxrehber.com/xtb?cmtx_sort=5&sef=xtb#cmtx_comments

Is there way to solve this with an extra rewrite rule, or am I in the wrong direction?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found the simple solution for that: I just added "[QSA]" at the end of the rule as below:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /kurum.php?sef=$1 [QSA]
```

Source : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

> Modifying the Query String

By default, the query string is passed through unchanged. You can, however, create URLs in the substitution string containing a query string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the query string. When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark. To combine new and old query strings, use the [QSA] flag.